# What does expression "naked to the world" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

What does expression "naked to the world" mean? I've heard it in a series Suits, season 2, episode 4, at the 20th minute.

Full sentence:
"Give me the address and tell Donna to hurry up. I'm naked to the world down here".

Comment: I'm going to need slightly more context than that, but based on that sentence alone, I'd guess that he's saying that he's out in the open and exposed to some danger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the definitions of *[naked](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/naked)* is

> Exposed to harm; unprotected or vulnerable:
>   John looked naked and defenseless without his glasses

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

The whole phrase would suggest that the person is in a hostile environment, an unfriendly world.

The term is also used to suggest an emotional vulnerability, or transparency, especially one taken on voluntarily after a period of personal reticence.

> Being without addition, concealment, disguise, or embellishment: the naked facts; *naked ambition.*

*[American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=naked)*

Answer (score 1):

Two lawyers talking about a lawsuit against a car company.  One has found what he believes to be a crucial witness, a former employee of the company, without whose testimony the lawyers can't win their suit.  The second lawyer tells the first to give him the address of the witness and to tell Donna, the paralegal, to hurry up and get ready to depose the witness.

"Naked to the world" means unprotected, completely vulnerable.  That is, Without the crucial testimony, he can't win.